# how to do pagination logic

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

Can anyone provide some idea/logic to write the pagination logic for the pages to pull specified record per page its pulling records fine form database using hibernate . The information i have is total number of pages for that search- 10 records per page also i am been sent the both the previous and next page number(no problem writing the logic all i need to do i pull that info and populate. I am also getting the info which page i am on. I can only display 10 pages like below

```
<previous 1 |2 |3 | 4| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 next>
```

Say if total pages are 15 and when user click last 10 then it need to display like this

```
<previous 2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 |11 next>
```

This is my jsp

```
<c:forEach var="status1" items="${list1}">
                                        <c:set var="wins" ><fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${status1.noOfPages}" /></c:set>
                                        <c:set var="wins1" ><fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${status1. currentpage}" /></c:set>
                                        <%int i = 0;%>
                                        <%int k = 0;%>
                                        <%int l = 1;%>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${wins1 eq 1}">
                                                <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="#">[First]</a>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <a style="font-size: 18px;" href=LibraryBookList.do?pageIndex=<%=l%>>[First]</a>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${wins1 eq 1}">
                                                <a href="#">[Previous]</a>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <a href="LibraryBookList.do?pageIndex=${wins1-1}">[Previous]</a>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${wins}" varStatus="loop">
                                            <a style="font-size: 18px;" href=LibraryBookList.do?pageIndex=<%=++k%>><%=++i%></a>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${wins1 eq wins}">
                                                <a href="#">[Next]</a>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <a href="LibraryBookList.do?pageIndex=${wins1+1}">[Next]</a>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${wins1 eq wins}">
                                                <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="#"/>>[Last]</a>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <a style="font-size: 18px;" href=LibraryBookList.do?pageIndex=<c:out value="${wins}"/>>[Last]</a>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: http://java-x.blogspot.in/2006/12/paging-in-jsp-with-hibernate.html http://www.javabeat.net/2008/10/pagination-using-hibernate-and-jsp/ http://mrbool.com/how-to-handle-pagination-using-jsp-pages/28345

Answer (score 0):

i tried it once a time My solution that i tried :

```
<%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>
    <c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
        <td><a href="employee.do?page=${currentPage - 1}">Previous</a></td>
    </c:if>

    <%--For displaying Page numbers.
    The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
                        <td>${i}</td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><a href="employee.do?page=${i}">${i}</a></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <%--For displaying Next link --%>
    <c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
        <td><a href="employee.do?page=${currentPage + 1}">Next</a></td>
    </c:if>
```

i hope my solution will help you.

Comment: it is givein me the which page am i active

Comment: But in mine it giving all data in pages

Comment: k its giving me that all pages....I want to fix the number pages per page is to three like above u can see my example..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to all the required fields like pageNo, NoOfRows to be displayed in each page. You just need to use the following logic in your serverside hibernate criteria everytime an user clicks any of the page number.

```
criteria.setFirstResult((this.page - 1) * this.rows);
criteria.setMaxResults(this.rows.intValue());       
this.searchResults = criteria.list();
```

Comment: int s = (pageIndex * numberOfRecordsPerPage) - numberOfRecordsPerPage;
            Map<String, List<LibraryBookForm>> map = new HashMap<String, List<LibraryBookForm>>();
            Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String qry = "From LibraryBookListEntity ";
            Query crit = ses.createQuery("From  LibraryBookListEntity");
            crit.setFirstResult(s);
            crit.setMaxResults(numberOfRecordsPerPage);
            List list = crit.list(); This is my code at the server side how to implement the logic for it

Comment: int s = (pageIndex - 1) *  numberOfRecordsPerPage;

Comment: I am getting same thing ...what i expected is i want to show only three records per page when i click next after that as to increment....and decrements..

Comment: On clicking next you need to implement logic to increment pageIndex so that you get the correct results. If you do not increment the pageIndex you will keep on getting same results

Comment: am getting every pages properly... could u plz see my scenario wht i expeted..in the above example.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I done this way and it works I did in Oracle ATG Commerce.

```
<fmt:parseNumber var="totalPages" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${totalOrdersCount/howMany}" />
                            <fmt:parseNumber var="stNo" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="1" />
                            <c:if test="${pgNo > 5 }">
                                <fmt:parseNumber var="x" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${(pgNo%5)}" />
                                <fmt:parseNumber var="y" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${(pgNo/5)-1}" />
                                <fmt:parseNumber var="stNo" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${1+(y*5)+x}" />
                            </c:if>
                            <fmt:parseNumber var="endNo" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${stNo+5-1}" />
                            <c:if test="${endNo >= totalPages}">
                                <fmt:parseNumber var="endNo" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${totalPages+1}" />
                            </c:if>
                            <div class="grid-footer">
                                <div class="pagination help-main-pagination product-pagination">
                                    <ul class="pull-right">
                                        <c:if test="${(pgNo - 1) >= 1}">
                                            <li><a class="prev control" href="/lwoms/list/index.jsp?pgNo=${pgNo - 1}">Prev</a></li>
                                        </c:if>
                                         <c:forEach begin="${stNo}" end="${endNo}" var="i">
                                        <%--    <li><a class="active" href="/lwoms/list/index.jsp?pgNo=<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></a></li> --%>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${pgNo eq i}">
                                                    <li><a class="active" href="/lwoms/list/index.jsp?pgNo=<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></a></li>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <li><a href="/lwoms/list/index.jsp?pgNo=<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></a></li>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <c:if test="${(pgNo + 1) <= totalPages}">
                                            <li><a class="next control" href="/lwoms/list/index.jsp?pgNo=${pgNo + 1}">Next</a></li>
                                        </c:if>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Hope this help!